# Toggle Switch State Based on JSON data - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am showing my JSON parsed data in data table and want to change status on change of switch in database and onscreen.

```
    rows: _Clist.map(
          ((clist) => DataRow(cells: [
    DataCell(
                  Center(
                    child: (
                        CupertinoSwitch(
                          activeColor: Color(0xFF2ECC71),
                          trackColor: Color(0xFFEFEFEF),
                          value: _SStatus = clist.status == 1 ? true : false,
                          onChanged: (bool newValue) {
                            this.setState(() {
                              _SStatus = newValue;
                            });
                            print(_SStatus.toString());
                          },
                      )
                    )
                  ),
                )
    ])),
    ).toList(),
```

Comment: so what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: Check this video: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vtN6ulL_U-5C2VYrTSjDkw2mYUEnakUe/view?usp=sharing

Comment: print() showing status is changing but onscreen all the checkboxes are changing.

Comment: Change the value to _SStatus==null?(clist.status == 1 ? true : false):_SStatus

Comment: getting the same result, all the switches are getting on and off.

Comment: To update each item status separately you need to build the JSON as data class object and use a setter function to update the status like clist.setSwitchStatus(newValue);

Comment: Any helping code? As I am in a learning phase, this is my first project.

Answer (score 0):

Create data class to assign JSON item

```
class DataClist{
  bool status; 

  DataClist.fromJSON(dynamic map) :
    status = map['status']==null?false:(map['status']==1?true:false);

  setSwitchStatus(bool newstatus){
    status = newstatus;
  }
}
```

Parse the JSON data as list of DataClist

```
List<DataClist> _clist = (json['items'] as List).map((e) => DataClist.fromJSON(e)).toList();
```

Now apply the list items to your row builder

```
rows: _clist.map(((clist) => DataRow(cells: [
    DataCell(
        Center(
          child: (
              CupertinoSwitch(
                activeColor: Color(0xFF2ECC71),
                trackColor: Color(0xFFEFEFEF),
                value: clist.status,
                onChanged: (bool newValue) {
                  this.setState(() {
                    clist.setSwitchStatus(newValue);
                  });
                },
            )
          )
        ),
      )
    ])),
    ).toList(),
```

Comment: Thanks for the help: here's my code https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EM3w6i5KkuSmLY6OyNmp-LrXyb5_x5e9/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Also update the CupertinoSwitch widget as per above sample

Comment: Stackoverflow guid you to understand the issue. You have to fix the issue your self or hire a freelancer to get the job done.